# SAS Viya - Environment Manager: Job triggers

Tags: triggers, sas, jobs

I am currently looking into SAS Viya 3.4 to replace SAS 9.4.
Now I was curious to see the possibilities of the Environment Manager in scheduling Jobs and mantaining and creating Job flows. However, I noticed that I could only Drag and Drop Jobs in a flow and connect them with very few configurable options. Also as a trigger to start a Jobflow I was only able to select a time event. I am wondering if there are other trigger types to choose from. Like a Job will be triggered if a specific table exists or a file exists [or ...]. Neither did I see the possibility to trigger/start a job based on the return code of the previous job.
Also it does not seem to be smart enough to make sure two jobs don't access a library with write access at the same time.
I can't see how SAS Viya could replace a Job Orchestration Tool. However, I feel like the tool was built to replace such an Orchestration Tool. Did I miss something or is it just not possible to do  so with the Environment Manager in SAS Viya?
Any help/insights is highly appreciated. I already searched through the documentation but could not find anything.. Maybe I was just looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Why 3.4 and not 3.5 (or Viya 4)?

If you want to use Viya with your own Job Orchestration software you can consider this tool (built by my team):  https://cli.sasjs.io/job/

We deployed it on Jenkins for this customer: https://www.sas.com/en_us/news/press-releases/2021/july/sas-partnership-with-lloyds-list-intelligence.html